Retrieving Gradient Colors from Google Slides API in Node.js?
I'm working on a project where I need to programmatically retrieve the gradient colors applied to shapes in Google Slides presentations using Node.js. I've been exploring the Google Slides API documentation but couldn't find a clear way to accomplish this.
Could someone please provide guidance or point me in the right direction on extracting gradient color information from shapes using the Google Slides API in a Node.js environment? Any examples or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!
